# Kotlin JavaScript Date.now() return type

Tags: javascript, datetime, kotlin

I was wondering why the Kotlin JavaScript `Date` class returns a Double for the [`getTime`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-date/get-time.html) function. According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime), the `getTime` function should return the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

I know that JS doesn't have a 64 bit numeric representation, but since Kotlin [emulates Longs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-to-kotlin-interop.html#representing-kotlin-types-in-javascript) I feel like the value returned by `Date.now()` and `Date().getTime()` should be a Long. At the very least it would make more sense to return an Int.

Is there any reason that it returns a Double instead of a whole number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate reasons for that: consistency and performance.
But before I get into that please note that you can easily get the desired behavior via extensions, e.g.:

```
inline val Date.time get() = getTime().toLong()

println(Date().time) // 1522757176433
```

1. Consistency. As you can see in the Date [documentation page](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-date/index.html#date), it an [external](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-interop.html#external-modifier) class. Which means it just describes an existing JavaScript API. Is it a good design decision to reuse it as it? Maybe not. But it has a benefit of being familiar to the JS folks. Changing the return type of a single function ruins that and makes the whole API quite inconsistent.
2. Performance. It is possible hide the original `getTime` and create a helper function instead. But keep in mind that in order to emulate Long Kotlin creates an object with 2 Number's. Creation, comparison, binary operations, storage - emulated Long's perform a lot worse than native JS Numbers.

Summing up. Changing the return type would make the API inconsistent and inefficient. If you value semantics over performance, just write a few helper functions.

P.S. I think the Date API will be redesigned at some point to make it possible to use it in multiplatform projects. But that's another story.

Comment: Thank you! Thank all makes perfect sense. Just the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin use **Date().time**  .It will return the long Values you will get whole number

```
   val s= Date().time
   print(s)
```

for example

```
    val date = "01-02-2018 07:05:00.999"
    val fmt = SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.S") //parse date based your format
    var myDate: Date? = null
    try {
        myDate = fmt.parse(date)
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    println(myDate)
    val timestamp = myDate!!.time //timestamp values in long only not double
    println(timestamp)
```

Comment: This is assuming a Kotlin project written for the JVM. My question is in regards to JavaScript Kotlin projects.